How the audio file was played?
I have been trying to play an audio file for a long time but I fail every time. I just want to play this audio file:-
assets/voices/en.mp3
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ok1/consconses.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class button extends StatelessWidget {
  button({super.key});
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: OkPrimaryColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
           player.play(DeviceFileSource("assets/voices/en.mp3")); 

      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 30),
        child: okWord(fontSize: 23),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Every time I find an unexpected error or press the button in the end to find that nothing happened


Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset:
"assets/voices/en.mp3"". The asset does not exist or has empty data.).

I believe this is most likely the error message you are getting. It is not displayed in the console.
Remove assets from the mp3 path and you should be fine.
Also it is better to use a stateful widget so you can dispose the player properly when it is not in use.
Also ensure the file(s) you are trying to play are properly referenced from your pubspec.yaml file.
Below is a sample code.
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child:ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: ()async {
          await player.setSource(AssetSource("voices/en.mp3"));

          await player.resume(); 

      },
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 30),
        child: Text("Play sound"),
      ),
    )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

